# Execute a function on currently non-existing ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my page, which calls a jQuery function like this:

```
$('[id^=edit]').one('click',function (){
    id = $(this).attr('id')
    changedId = id.replace('edit', '') // cut off the word 'edit'
    oldValue = $('#' + changedId).text()
    $('#' + changedId).html("<input class='myInput' type='text' value='" + oldValue +"'/>");
    $(this).addClass('success');
    $(this).attr('id', changedId+'Button');
    $(this).text("save it")
});
```

Basically, this click creates an input element in a paragraph, and adds another class to the button, and then changes it's ID.

I would like to write a second function which will be executed when the button with the NEW ID is clicked. For example:

```
$('[id$=Button]').click(function(){
    alert("it works");

});
```

Is something like this possible? That new function would trigger some AJAX call to my Django app, but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your event to be delegated to a not yet existing element, use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '[id$=Button]', function(){
```

Comment: @JustinEthier Did you mean your comment as an explanation ?

Comment: Your answer kinda works. Only problem is that the second function is executed immediately, eg. it doesn't wait for my click. First function executes, and alert pops up instantly.

Comment: Oooook, I kinda figured it out (with a help from a friend). Solution for my problem was to not change the ID of currently clicked button, but to add another one.

Then dystroy's answer works, and I am thankfull.

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery:

```
$('#' + changedId + 'Button').live('click', function(event) {
   alert('it works');
});
```

Comment: live was long deprecated, and has now been removed.